# Geolocation call in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, reactjs

I have  code here for a very simple weather app, but I would like it snag a geolocation and build the ajax call to the wunderground API using the returned latitude and longitude of the user. The app so far is :

```js
var WeatherApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {};
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var vm = this; 
        var url = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/[apikey]/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json";
        var getWeather = function (res) {
            // Update component 
            if (vm.isMounted()) {
                var obv = res["current_observation"];
                vm.setState(obv);
            } else {
                console.log(res.text);
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }).done(getWeather);
    },
    render: function () {
        var weather = this.state.weather;
        var temp = this.state.temp;
        return (
            <div>
                <Sphere weather={ weather } temp={ temp }/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
  

var Sphere = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var skyClass = this.props.temp > 30 ? "sun" : "clouds";
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={ skyClass }></div>
                <div>{this.props.weather}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<WeatherApp />, document.body);
```

and I have this vanilla js function to use geolocation to build the url

```js
var x = document.getElementById("location");
function requestCurrentPosition(){
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(useGeoData);
        }
}

 function useGeoData(position){
   x.innerHTML = (" http://api.wunderground.com/api/[apikey]/geolookup/q/" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + ".json");
  };
requestCurrentPosition();
```

...but how do I translate that output url into a React prop that my $ajax call can access to?

Comment: Why don't you just call `requestCurrentPosition` from componentDidMount, and use the callback to initiate the ajax request which in turn sets the state?

Comment: If you have an answer to the question you can write you own answer and then accept it. This is preferable than editing the word "solved" into the question.